# Linq fill data for nested List<T>

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I have this Model

```
public class CPMC
{
    public int CPMCId { get; set; }
    public List<TPM> tpm = new List<TPM>();
    public List<TPMC> tpmc = new List<TPMC>();
}
public class TPMC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 Amount { get; set; }
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public Int64 PAmount { get; set; }
    public int CPMCId { get; set; }
}
public class TPM
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 Amount { get; set; }
    public int VAT { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public int CPMCId { get; set; }
}
```

The data for this List is 5k records of CPMCId and 50k records for each child list inside with condition is

```
List<int> CPMCIdList = aPP.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.CPMCId)).Distinct().ToList(); 
                List<CPMC> cpl = (from ap in CPMCIdList 
                                  select new CPMC
                                  {
                                      CPMCId = ap,
                                      tpm = tpml.Where(x=>x.CPMCId == ap).ToList(),
                                      tpmc = tpmcl.Where(x=>x.CPMCId == ap).ToList()
                                  }).ToList();
```

But it takes a lot of time to fill data in List. Can you guys have a better implement for this solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not using EntityFramework but simply linq? Given the structure and  large amount of data, I'd expect it to be slow simply because you're placing everything in-memory (5k CPMCId and 50k records for each child list)

Comment: Ya, I'm using simple linq query. What would I do to make it faster

Comment: what are tmpl and tpmcl and why aren't they hashmap-backed IDictionary<int,T> (eg. Dictionary)?

Comment: @moreON that's 2 sub class separate then they arent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the two inner loop linear searches (LINQ `Where` operators), your current implementation has `O(K*N*M)` time complexity, where `K=CPMCIdList.Count`, `N=tpml.Count`, `M=tpmcl.Count`.

It can be reduced to the much faster `O(K+M+N)` by using the LINQ [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1) operators which internally use a quite efficient hash based lookup:

```
var cpl =
    (from cpmcId in CPMCIdList
     join tpm in tpml on cpmcId equals tpm.CPMCId into tpmg
     join tpmc in tpmcl on cpmcId equals tpmc.CPMCId into tpmcg
     select new CPMC
     {
         CPMCId = cpmcId,
         tpm = tpmg.ToList(),
         tpmc = tpmcg.ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: This seem good, thanks for the group join keywork. I accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

First, let's reduce your problem to the minimum case:

You have the following types:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> bs = new List<B>();
    public List<C> cs = new List<C>();
}

public class B
{
    public int CPMCId { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int CPMCId { get; set; }
}
```

Apparently, you have a list of `A`'s, `B`'s and `C`s

```
List<A> as;
List<B> bs;
List<C> cs;
```

you're looking to create a list of `A`'s

Now first let's take a look at why your solution is slow.

What you're doing is first creat a list of all the ID's you want, and then, for each ID, search all records that match. That means you're scanning the child lists entirely for every ID. That's clearly not optimal.

The operation you are looking for is called `Outer Join` in `SQL`. Unfortunately, Linq doesn't have an equivalent operation out of the box.

So we're going to that ourselves. It's possible to make a generic version of this approach, but it's not entirely straightforward. What we're going to do is sort the A's and the B's by their `CPMCId`, and then take all the matching records that have a corresponding ID in the list of `A`s:

```
IEnumerable<A> make_as(IEnumerator<B> ordered_bs, IEnumerator<C> ordered_cs, IEnumerator<int> ordered_ids) {
  //make sure the current element of bs and cs is at the first element, not before it.
  if(!ordered_bs.MoveNext() || !ordered_cs.MoveNext())
    throw new ArgumentException("empty bs or cs");

  while(ordered_ids.MoveNext()) {
    nextid = ordered_ids.Current;
    var a = new A(){
      id = nextId;
    };
    //process the B's
    while(ordered_bs.Current.CPMCId < nextid) //not in the list, skip it {
      ordered_bs.MoveNext();
    }
    while(ordered_bs.Current.CPMCId == nextid) //matching, add to the list {
      a.bs.add(ordered_cs.Current);
      if(!orderd_bs.MoveNext()) break; //move bs forward. If b's is empty, we're done here
    }
    //do the same for the C's
    while(ordered_cs.Current.CPMCId < nextid) {
      ordered_cs.MoveNext();
    }
    while(ordered_cs.Current.CPMCId == nextid) {
      a.cs.add(ordered_cs.Current);
      if(!ordered_cs.MoveNext()) break;
    }
    yield return a;
  }
}

var result = make_as(
  bs.orderBy(b => b.PCMCId).GetEnumerator(),
  cs.orderBy(c => c.PCMCId).GetEnumerator(),
  as.Select(a => a.id).OrderBy(id => id).Distinct().GetEnumerator()
).ToList()
```

Some notes:

I'm getting the impression that this is a part of a solution that already had some processing done. When you know that you're going to need all ID's, you don't need the original list of `A`'s at all, and the nextId will be the lowest `Current` of the `A`'s and `B`s

It's also quite possible that right now you're in a bit of a hole you dug yourself in to. It's quite possible that you could do this more efficiently - and more elegantly - further "upstream" in your code.

As a last note, this snippet does not work when either the list of `B`'s or the list of `C`'s contain no elements. In that case, a simple GroupBy is sufficient.

Comment: Caveat Emptor! This snippet was compiled, tested and typechecked only in my mind.

Comment: Nah, this is too complex, I use the answer of @Ivan Stoev and get better peformance with simple implement. Thanks